# UITextField reference from rightView

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I am setting a `UIButton` to the `rightView` of a `UITextField`. Furthermore, I am setting adding a target-action to the `UIButton` via

```
myButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

I would like to know how I can access the `UITextField` from the method specified as `buttonPressed` where its method signature looks like:

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

}
```

I have tried

```
sender.superview as! UITextField
```

but I seem to be getting a `nil`.

Also, I am unable to use tags as it is already in use for another purpose.

**EDIT:**

For further information, `myButton.addTarget()` happens inside a `UITableViewCell`, which is why I don't have an `outlet` to the `UITextField` in the view controller.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: why can't you set tag?

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, I am using tags for another purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct

I tried as follows and it is working for me

Custom `textField` :

```
    var textFiled = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(20.0, 50.0, 100.0, 33.0))
    textFiled.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect

    let purpleImageButton = UIButton(frame :CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 30))
    purpleImageButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    purpleImageButton.setTitle("T", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    purpleImageButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    textFiled.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
    textFiled.rightView = purpleImageButton
    self.view.addSubview(textFiled)
```

Function `buttonPressed` :

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let textF : UITextField = sender.superview as UITextField
    textF.text = "Hello"
}
```

Before Clicking

[image]

After Clicking on button of textField :

[image]

Hope you will find the problem.

Here is Xcode version 6.1. So, My example will be as per Swift 1.1.

Comment: I just tried this, and it still seems to be returning nil.

Comment: @coldbuffet changed the answer